# $body.find('element') not working when called inside .then() chain

Tags: jquery, testing, automated-tests, cypress

In my Cypress test I'm trying to check if an element exists on the page.

If it exists, do something, else do something else.
I'm getting the body then finding the element then checking if it exists using .find() and is.(':visible')

When I do it this way, isVisible is always false, despite the element existing:

```
cy.get( 'body' ).then(( $body ) => {
      const isVisible = $body.find( 'div[style="white-space: nowrap;"]' ).is( ':visible' );
      // never executes
      if ( isVisible ) {
        cy.log( 'It is visible' );
```

If I do .find() right after .get like this, it finds it and isVisible is true, but the element is not always present on the page, so this .find() will fail sometimes.

```
cy.get( 'body' ).find( 'div[style="white-space: nowrap;"]' ).then(( $body ) => {
      const isVisible = $body.is( ':visible' );     
      if ( isVisible ) {
        cy.log( 'It is visible' );
```

Is my logic wrong? Is there a better way to check for an element on the page?

HTML Structure:

```
<body style> 
    <div id="__next"> 
        <div class>
            <nav data-baseweb="header-navigation" role="navigation" class="ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au">
                <ul class="ai av aw ax ay az b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8">
                    <li class="b9 ay b7 az b8 b4 ba b3 b5"> 
                    <li>
                <ul>
            <nav>
            <div style="padding:0" class="bb bc bd">
                <div class="ai be bf bg bh">
                    <div class="ai bx bv by bi bz">
                        <div class="ai c0 c1 b6 c2 c3 bf b1 c4 au">
                            <div class="ai c5 bs bt c6 c7 c8 c9 bf">
                                <div class="ai bv b1 bw bg">
                                    <h6 data-baseweb="typo-headingxsmall"> <h6>
                                    <div class>
                                        <button disabled class="css-jfmp5u e1g3plmq1"> <button>
                                        <div style="white-space: nowrap;"> <div>
                                        <button class="css-jfmp5u e1g3plmq1"> <button>
                                    <div>
                                <div>
                            <div>
                        <div>
                    <div>
                <div>
            <div>
        <div>
    <div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the presence of the element on the DOM then use the `length` attribute in jquery.

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('div[style="white-space: nowrap;"]').length > 0) {
    //element exists do something
  } else {
    //Element doesn't exists. Do Something
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried this but the if statement still isn't evaluating to true. For .find() to locate the element, does it matter where the element is in regards to the body? For example, the element I'm trying to assert 'div[style="white-space: nowrap;"]' is nested inside a lot of other <div> elements.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter where the element is. I would suggest you use a different locator for this. If you can add the HTML of the element you are looking for, I can help with the locator. Also since we are using the Jquery method, it is important to make sure that the element in question is properly loaded on the DOM.

Comment: Okay bear with me, it is nested within a lot of <div> elements, but essentially this is the structure.

<body style> 
 <div id> 
  <div class> 
   <div style>
    <div class>
     <div class>
      <div class>
       <div class>
        <div class>
         <div class>
          <div style="white-space: nowrap;"> <div>
         <div>
        <div>
       <div>
      <div>
     <div>
    <div>
   <div>
  <div>
 <div>
<body>

Comment: Added the HTML to the post for readability

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info to give an exact answer (you've removed too much detail from the HTML), but you need to `cy.get()` some element that **always** rendered on the page, but only after page loading is complete.

`cy.get('body')` won't do it because it is on the page from the start, so your inner visibility test runs immediately but the inner HTML is still loading.

So presume `div[class="always-rendered"]` is such an element, you can make use of Cypress retry as well as doing a conditional check.

```js
cy.get('div[class="always-rendered"]').then($el => {
  const isVisible = $el.find('div[style="white-space: nowrap;"]').is( ':visible' );
  if (isVisible) {
    console.log( 'It is visible' );
```

Do not use `cy.log()` to debug, use `console.log()`

And `div[style="white-space: nowrap;"]` is a really bad selector, there could be lots of element with that style.

Comment: I've updated the HTML to have more elements, a lot of the <div> names above the element I'm trying to find have dynamic names.